# Facebook App is not working when using Proxy Server

Tags: proxy, facebook

I have Android Galaxy device. I have setup Wifi Settings to a Proxy Server(local intranet IP). When I open the Facebook app I will get *Error Loading News Feed*, *Connection Lost*, etc.

Is it possible to use Facebook app on Android using a Proxy Server?

Comment: Does your proxy server support ssl?

Comment: @edvinas.me, Thanks for reply. My Proxy Server is my internal ip address 192.168.1.X. My app without ssl works but Facebook not. Is there anything I need to do to make my proxy server support ssl.

Comment: @edvinas.me, Actually you are right. I was mistakenly set `Fiddler Tools > Fiddler Options > HTTPS Decrypt HTTPS Traffic box`